# Word or phrase referring to an author's most famous/noteworthy works

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember that the most famous/noteworthy works of literary merit are termed the canon,but is there a particular word or phrase that means the most famous/noteworthy works of a particular author?  Could I use "canon" here too?

Comment: An artist's complete works of art can also be called his "oeuvre."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An author's or artist's important work that shows her potential and reflects later development is often referred to as a *[seminal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seminal)* work

> containing or contributing the seeds of later development : creative, original *a seminal book*

SUPPLEMENT

An artist's most significant work is often referred to as a *[chef d'oeuvre](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chef+d%27oeuvre)*

> a masterpiece especially in art or literature

The group of her or his masterpieces could be called *chefs d'oeuvre*.

Answer (score 4):

The most famous and noteworthy work of an author, composer, director, etc. is most commonly known as that person’s ***[magnum opus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/magnum%20opus)***.

*Magnum opus* is Latin for ‘great work’, and as the form *magnum* ‘great’ belies, *opus* ‘work’ is neuter in Latin. Its plural form, *opera*, was later reinterpreted as a feminine noun in the singular (since these ended in *-a* in the stage of Vulgar Latin or Early French/Italian at the time). The Modern French result of that is *œuvre*, which has also been borrowed into English as ***oeuvre***, used both an author/composer/director/etc.’s entire catalogue works (as noted in Francis James’ answer), and for an individual piece in that catalogue.

Comment: Yes, but that refers to a single work. The question asks about "works", plural. Is `magna opera` in common use?

Comment: I didn’t even see the s there in the question—must have read over it too quickly. If specifically talking about several works, I guess I would use _magnum opuses_ in a normal conversation or _magna opera_ in a text.

Comment: "magnum opuses"?! Perish forbid.

Comment: In a normal, spoken conversation, I would probably be more likely to use a completely transparent plural (depending on whom I’m speaking to of course) to lessen the risk of not being understood. Similarly, I most often _say_ ‘octopuses’, ‘stadiums’, ‘saunas’, ‘sagas, and ‘banshees’ in speech. In writing, especially in academic writing, I would be more likely to opt for the endonymic plurals ‘magna opera’, ‘octopodes’, ‘stadia’, ‘saunat’, ‘sögur’, and ‘mná sí’ (or ‘mná sídhe’ for that matter), in descending order of likelihood.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet:  Just make sure you 1) don't use "antennae" to indicate two or more conductors by which electromagnetic waves are sent out or received, consisting commonly of a wire or set of wires; and 2) don't use "antennas" to indicate the jointed, movable, sensory appendages occurring in pairs on the heads of insects and most other arthropods.  If you do, I'll call you on it every time!  I'm giving you fair warning.

Answer (score 2):

**[Masterpieces](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/masterpiece)** or **[Masterworks](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/masterwork)**

The singular of these terms originally referred to work of such high standards as to qualify the creator to be ranked as a guild master.

Masterpieces and masterworks should be considered works that meet that standard.

Today, the terms commonly refer to outstanding work in art or craft, as well as to *the* greatest work of its creator.

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts -

Anthology

Compendium

Highlighted works

Selected works

Core contributions